# Strange compilation error for a move constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, move

I'm trying to make a move constructor but I get the error

```
expected ',' or '...' before '&&' token
```

This is the line that's causing the trouble:

```
List(List&& list) noexcept;
```

I also have a copy-constructor that looks similiar. Dont know if that might cause trouble:

```
List(const List& copy);
```

(this is all in the header file for my List class)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make sure you use a compiler that can compile C++11 code (and is set to do so), this is not valid in previous versions of the C++ standard

Comment: If you are using gcc or clang, you can enable C++11 features by passing `-std=c++0x`

Comment: ...or `-std=c++11` in newer versions (GCC 4.7).